# Button to teleport you a specific part of a scrollable region, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the tkinter code I have used to create a scrollable region. I was wondering if there was a way I could add in a button which when you pressed it teleports you to a specific section of the scrollable region. Is it even possible?

```
self.canvas1 = Canvas(master, width=1200, height=700, scrollregion=(0,0,800,3000))        
self.horizontalscroll = Scrollbar(master, orient=HORIZONTAL)
self.horizontalscroll.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
self.horizontalscroll.config(command=self.canvas1.xview)
self.verticalscroll = Scrollbar(master, orient=VERTICAL)
self.verticalscroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
self.verticalscroll.config(command=self.canvas1.yview)
self.canvas1.config(xscrollcommand=self.horizontalscroll.set, yscrollcommand=self.verticalscroll.set, bg="#4c5059")
self.canvas1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
self.frame1 = Frame(master)
self.frame1.configure(bg="#4c5059")
self.MainWindow = self.canvas1.create_window(10, 10, window=self.frame1, anchor='nw')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call the `xview_moveto` and `yview_moveto` methods to scroll anywhere you want. These take a value representing a percentage. Top/left is zero, bottom/right is 1.0, the middle is .5, etc.

For example, to show the bottom-right corner you could do this:

```
self.canvas1.xview_moveto(1.0)
self.canvas1.yview_moveto(1.0)
```

Comment: Hey, Im having some trouble, Ive set what you told me as the command of a button, but it doesn't seem to work, when I start the programme it performs the move even if I don't push the button

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry I'm new to programming